# R: How to include static pdf in vignette for CRAN?

Tags: r, cran, vignette

I tried to follow the instructions in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf which shows how to include static pdf in vignette for [cran](/questions/tagged/cran). However, after following the instructions and creating the PDFs and asis files, I get the folowing warning when doing a check in [r](/questions/tagged/r) `version 3.6.2` on Windows.

```r
Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package:
    'inst/doc/concepts.pdf'
    'inst/doc/convenience-features.pdf'
    'inst/doc/custom-group-by.pdf'
    'inst/doc/data-table-syntax.pdf'
    'inst/doc/glm.pdf'
    'inst/doc/group-by.pdf'
    'inst/doc/ingesting-data.pdf'
    'inst/doc/intro-disk-frame.pdf'
```

How do I resolve this? I checked, every one of these pdfs are in the `vignettes` folder and I also tried putting them into the `doc` folder and I still get the same warning.

The folder structure and project structure can be see here in [this repo](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame)

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `.Rbuildignore`

Comment: It's quite long but I have `^doc$`. Is that the problem?

Comment: I'd say so `If you wish to exclude a specific file or directory (the most common use case), you MUST anchor the regular expression. For example, to exclude a directory called notes, use ^notes$. ` [source](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html)

Comment: I am confused, am I supposed to have `^doc$` in .Rbuildignore or not?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your explanation. I don't do anything in/with the `doc/` directory and also **don't** have it in my `.Rbuildignore`. I have no idea why you would put files belonging to the vignette into `inst/`. I have all my vignette files in `vignettes/`

Comment: I didn't put them there. It was just there. After I press Check in RStudio

Comment: And do you have these files in `inst/` in the source code directory or the built package? And why do you have `^doc$` in your buildignore?

Comment: Can't remember why I had ^doc$, but those files are generated by the vignette process I think

Comment: now i remove ^doc$ then I get this in note N  checking top-level files
   Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
     'doc'

Comment: Without seeing your package structure it's going to be difficult to tell but 1. There should be no `doc/` directory in your source code, neither at root nor in `inst/`. 2. When I run Check in RStudio, no files are copied to `inst` in the package source, **HOWEVER** there will be a directory `doc/` created in the **installed packages** directory...

Comment: Could you resolve your problem?

Comment: no no no no no no

Comment: Can you append your question with the structure of you project? And why is there a `doc` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Several of my packages just use the scheme first written about [here by Mark van der Loo](https://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2019/01/11/add-a-static-pdf-vignette-to-an-r-package/).

You can just look at several of my packages wheren generally I now places the sources in `vignettes/rmd` and have a `Makefile` put the pdfs in `vignettes/pdf`.  The key is to then use a simple Sweave run to just include the already-made body of the pdf vignette into a new document.

Comment: was it done on a Linux system or mac or Windows? Perhaps the issue is just windows

Comment: Works on all the same way because it relies on the original method: Sweave. (Which will need a minimal latex installation as we use latex to 'glue' a minimal pdf wrapper around the premade static vignette).  Works _great_ in my view.